# How To Change Class of h2 If It Has A value < 0 Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an `h2` element with live stock price and change details. I want to dynamically add the class `green` if the `h2` element has a value `> 0`. And if `h2` element has a value `< 0` I want to change the class from Green to Red using JavaScript. Here is my code.

Markup:

```
<h2 class="font-weight-bold mx-2"> 
    <?php echo "".$gold_chg." | ".$gold_chgp;; ?>% 
</h2>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeInputColor(h2, value){ 
    $(h2).removeClass(); 
    if (value < 0){ 
        $(h2).addClass('TransactionAmount'); 
    } else if(value >= 0.1 && value <= 9){ 
        $(h2).addClass('TransactionAmount.green'); 
    } else { 
       $(h2).addClass('high-risk'); 
    } 
 }
```

I want my JavaScript code to change the class based on value in H2 element.

Tried adding 'id="totalAmt"' to h2 element and following js code.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('totalAmt');

function colorChange() {
  if (myElement.textContent <= 0) {

    totalAmt.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    totalAmt.style.color = 'green';
  }
}
```

**Here is the complete code**

```
<?php
$urs = "https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD";
$json = file_get_contents('https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD');
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$item = $decoded->items;
$date = $decoded->date;
$gold_price = $item[0]->xauPrice;
$gold_chg = $item[0]->chgXau;
$gold_chgp = $item[0]->pcXag;
//echo "Gold price per Ounce on ".$gold_chg." is ".$gold_price;
 ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

<style type="text/css">
:root{--font-family-sans-serif:"Open Sans",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";--font-family-monospace:SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace}html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}body{background-color:#fff}.greeting h1{color:#515151;font-weight:lighter;font-size:32px;margin:1} 
"(Default CSS)" .greeting h2{color:#515151;font-weight:700;font-size:16px;margin:0}
</style>

<style type="text/css">

.green {
      color: green;
}
</style>

<!-- HTML Code -->

<div class="greeting">
  <h1 class="mx-2"> <?php echo $gold_price; ?> </h1>
<h2 id="stock" class="font-weight-bold mx-2"> <?php echo $gold_chg; ?> </h2>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

// add the id 'stock' to your heading
// <h2 id="stock"  class="font-weight-bold mx-2"></h2>

const heading = document.getElementById('stock');
if (parseInt(heading.innerHTML) > 0) {
  heading.classList.add('green');
}
else {
  // remove green if value drops below zero
  heading.classList.remove('green')
}

</script>
```

Result
[Image Link of HTML Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNYwv.png)

Comment: What code have you attempted so far to satisfy your class changing requirement?

Comment: So where are you actually _calling_ those JS functions you have shown us …?

Comment: And why are you trying to do this using client-side JS to begin with? Does the value dynamically change, _after_ the page has loaded? So far, this sounds as if you could simply add the class based on what the PHP variable `$gold_chg` contains already …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work

```
// add the id 'stock' to your heading
// <h2 id="stock" class="font-weight-bold mx-2"></h2>

const heading = document.getElementById('stock');
if (parseInt(heading.innerHTML) > 0) {
  heading.classList.add('green');
}
else {
  // remove green if value drops below zero
  heading.classList.remove('green')
}
```